# Fill in missing values in column with a different dataframe

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have an example dataframe that has a column which stores 3 letters of the alphabet per row. The dataframe also has 2 additional columns: date and colour:

```
Alphabet       Date   Colour
  ABC    2018-09-10   green
  DEF    2017-06-11   red
  GHI    2016-05-12   blue
  JKL            NA   yellow
  MNO            NA   orange
  PQR       Unknown   brown
```

Some of the dates are missing / unknown in this dataframe. I have another dataframe which also has a alphabet and a date column. This second dataframe includes the dates for the missing dates in the first dataframe:

```
Alphabet       Date   
  JKL    2017-06-07  
  MNO    2018-08-03   
  PQR    2019-10-07
  STU    2019-11-08
  VWX    2019-12-08
```

I want to fill in the missing dates from the first dataframe by matching the Alphabet records from both dataframes and then insert the dates from the second dataframe into the first dataframe.

Desired output:

```
Alphabet       Date   Colour
  ABC    2018-09-10   green
  DEF    2017-06-11   red
  GHI    2016-05-12   blue
  JKL    2017-06-07   yellow
  MNO    2018-08-03   orange
  PQR    2019-10-07   brown
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is a join with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, Date := i.Date, on = .(Alphabet)]
df1
#   Alphabet       Date Colour
#1:      ABC 2018-09-10  green
#2:      DEF 2017-06-11    red
#3:      GHI 2016-05-12   blue
#4:      JKL 2017-06-07 yellow
#5:      MNO 2018-08-03 orange
#6:      PQR 2019-10-07  brown
```

#### Update

Using the new 'df2n' dataset

```
i1 <- is.na(df1$Date)|df1$Date %in% "Unknown"
setDT(df1)[df2n[df2n$Alphabet %in% df1$Alphabet[i1],],
         Date := i.Date, on = .(Alphabet)]
df1
#   Alphabet       Date Colour
#1:      ABC 2018-09-10  green
#2:      DEF 2017-06-11    red
#3:      GHI 2016-05-12   blue
#4:      JKL 2017-06-07 yellow
#5:      MNO 2018-08-03 orange
#6:      PQR 2019-10-07  brown
```

---

Or using `match` from `base R`

```
i1 <- match(df2$Alphabet, df1$Alphabet)
df1$Date[i1] <- df2$Date
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Alphabet = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", 
"PQR"), Date = c("2018-09-10", "2017-06-11", "2016-05-12", NA, 
NA, "Unknown"), Colour = c("green", "red", "blue", "yellow", 
"orange", "brown")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(Alphabet = c("JKL", "MNO", "PQR"), Date = c("2017-06-07", 
"2018-08-03", "2019-10-07")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2a  <- structure(list(Alphabet = c("JKL", "MNO", "PQR", "STU", "VWX"
), Date = c("2017-06-07", "2018-08-03", "2019-10-07", "2019-11-08", 
"2019-12-08")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error message when I try your match method: NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments. I don't believe I have NAs in my dataframes.

Comment: @KakSchoen  I showed the data as well (which is a copy of your example) and it is working fine for me.  Please check if you have `factor` columns.  I assumed it as `character` class.  Convert to `character` if needed `df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character); df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.character)` and then apply

Comment: The example is also working for me, but my real dataset isn't. I checked my columns and they are all class characters, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @KakSchoen  Sorry, that is not reproducible for me

Comment: I'll try to clarify a bit further: I just tried your solution again but with a slight adjustment. I added a 4th row to df2, so now not every row from df2 matches with df1 (which is actually the case in my real dataset). This gives the the same error message that I was getting with my real dataset. So it seems that if the second dataframe has more rows that are not matching with the first dataframe, then the error occurs.

Comment: @KakSchoen  Based on the example, I assumed that there are no duplicates in the  second dataset for Alphabet

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated my post. So I have a second dataframe with many different variables in the "alphabet" column and I only need a small part of this second dataframe to fill in the first dataframe.

Comment: @KakSchoen  Updatedd with the new df2n dataset

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` we can `left_join` `df1` and `df2` and then use `coalesce` to fill in missing values.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = "Alphabet") %>%
   mutate(Date = coalesce(Date.y, Date.x)) %>%
  select(-Date.x, -Date.y)

#  Alphabet Colour       Date
#1      ABC  green 2018-09-10
#2      DEF    red 2017-06-11
#3      GHI   blue 2016-05-12
#4      JKL yellow 2017-06-07
#5      MNO orange 2018-08-03
#6      PQR  brown 2019-10-07
```